# How does bitcoin find the block locator hashes in the leveldb database?

Tags: network, leveldb

I am trying to understand how bitcoin core builds the list of block locator hashes needed for sendheaders and getheaders messages. I have looked on the [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getblocks) and I have seen that after the 10 most recent block hashes, it goes back exponentially until the genesis block.

So it seems that I have to get a block hash knowing its index in the blockchain. But how can bitcoin core find a block hash by its index? From my understanding leveldb lets you query data only by a key, and in this case the key is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it doesn't use LevelDB for this.

It has an in-memory data structure with all known block headers, each pointing back to its parent. It also has a vector with pointers to all block headers in the currently active chain.

To build locator objects, it simply looks in this vector at specific indexes.

Comment: So every time bitcoin core receives a new block it has to update both this data and the database, am I right?

Comment: Indeed, but the in-memory structure is very cheap to update.